# buildfire: Is it possible to access clock and alarms functions through buildfire sdk

Tags: buildfire

Is it possible to access the devices clock and alarm functions?  I haven't seen a buildfire plugin for this in the marketplace.

Comment: It would help if you could described in more detail the specific functionality that you're looking for. For example, if you want to alert a user at a specific point in time there are multiple ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Sure, for example if I wanted to have a buildfire app that plays a media file at a set time....sort of like a music alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the BuildFire [local notifications API](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Buildfire-Local-Notifications-API) **schedule** function to schedule an event.

Here's sample code:

```
var options = {
            title: 'Wake Up',
            text: 'Time to get moving',
            data: '',
            at: sendTime
        };

buildfire.notifications.localNotification.schedule(options, function (err, data) {

        });
```